# Is it possible to connect a TV to a PC surround sound system

Tags: audio, speakers, hdtv, sound-cards, sound-system

I recently bought an LG 49UH6030 4K TV. I've also had for quite a while a Creative Inspire T6600 6.1 surround sound speaker system.

My TV has a mini-jack output and an optical output. I would really like to use all the channels of the surround speaker system so the mini-jack is not really an option.

I have been checking for options to convert the optical output to the three-jack cables that come with the T6600 input. All I've been able to find are external sound cards for PC which are able to do that but need to be connected to a PC.

Since I currently don't have a PC constantly connected to my TV (would like to later on) what kind of device could I use to convert the sound output? Of course, budget-wise.

I found [this thing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013256ODG), but since I've never used one I don't know if the USB connection is for drivers and stuff or just for power.

Any ideas or recommendations? I mean I'm pretty happy with the sound of the TV, but the speakers are even better.